# Get data-id with ajax and pass it to php in the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get data-id with ajax and pass it to php in the same page, but when i click the button and i want to echo $_POST["postid"], nothing happen. Is there any mistake? i want to get postid. please help me, i am new in ajax and php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap css -->
    <!-- Fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button title="Reply" class="replyButton btn p-0 pr-1" name="reply" data-id="11"><i class="fas fa-reply"></i></button>
    <div id="mydiv">
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["postid"])){
            echo $_POST["postid"];
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.replyButton').on('click', function(){
            var postid = $(this).data('id');
            $post = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    'postid': postid
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $("#mydiv").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Do you load jQuery?

Comment: yes i already use jquery

Comment: Is test.php the page your are on?

Comment: yes, in the same page

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: And you really should use method instead of type

Comment: no error in console sir. i already change to method, still no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector in your jQuery is incorrect. Either change

```
<div class="mydiv">  <!-- selector .mydiv -->
```

To:

```
<div id="mydiv">  <!-- selector #mydiv -->
```

Or instead of `$("#mydiv")` use `$(".mydiv")` instead.

And since you're posting to the same php file, when the file receives a post you should only output the desired value i.e. `echo $_POST["postid"];` which the jQuery code will receive and place in the `div`.

Note:
Consider adjusting your PHP code to:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["postid"])){
        echo $_POST["postid"];
    } else {
?>
    <!-- Page content goes HERE -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you, it works! but why when i click the button, the button become 2?

Comment: `postid` should be the only content returned upon post, nothing else - no html. Normally you would have that at the top; output `postid` `if` it's a POST `else` load the page content.

Comment: how to do that sir? only echo post

Comment: @HarveyJeremy, please see note in my answer. Don't hesitate to upvote the answer if you find that helpful.